# There's an error "Temporal data comparison should have the same data type."

Tags: sql, partitioning, dolphindb

created table as below:

```py
login("admin", "123456")
if(existsDatabase("dfs://compoDB")){
    dropDatabase("dfs://compoDB")
}
    
n = 1000000
ID = rand(100, n)
dates = 2017.08.07T00:00:00.000..2017.08.08T00:00:00.000
date = rand(dates, n)
x = rand(10.0, n)
t = table(ID, date, x)
    
dbDate = database(, VALUE, 2017.08.07..2017.08.11)
dbID=database(, RANGE, 0 50 100)
db = database("dfs://compoDB", COMPO, [dbDate, dbID])
    
pt = db.createPartitionedTable(t, `pt, `date`ID)
pt.append!(t)
```

then executed query as below:

```py
select * from loadTable("dfs://compoDB", "pt") where date between 2017.08.07:2017.08.08
```

there's an error message:

```py
Temporal data comparison should have the same data type.
```

why

Answer (score 0):

The type of date in where clause should be the same as that in the table. The correct query statement is as follows:

```py
select * from loadTable("dfs://compoDB", "pt") where date between 2017.08.07T00:00:00.000:2017.08.08T23:59:59.999
```